# Show button conditionally, based on database value

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am creating an online 'store' using a MongoDB database to update inventory. One option in the storefront is to 'Buy' an item (which decrements the qty value by one; however, I would only like that button to be displayed if the inventory (qty in MongoDB) is > 0. I feel like I need a ternary operator, but I'm stumped on the syntax of creating that conditional statement. Do I use disable? If so, I can't figure out how to 'enable' in ternary. Or, should I use .display? Thanks for any help. Here is my code for the button as of now.

```
<a class="btn btn-success" href="/product/buy/<%= product._id %> ">
<i class="icon-shopping-cart icon-large"></i> Buy</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<%= product.qty > 0 ? <a class="btn btn-success" href="/product/buy/<%= product._id %> ">
<i class="icon-shopping-cart icon-large"></i> Buy</a> : <p> Unavailabe </p> %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I just get formatting errors when I try that. It makes sense when I read it, but I can't quite sort out errors in the squids and flounders.